# How to make comparator for a map of pairs cpp

Tags: dictionary, stl, comparator

My code is like this . Now I want to sort this map of pairs based on increasing order of the second value of pair. I have tried to make a comparator but seems its not correct. Please  someone help me correcting it

```
bool cmp1(map < string, pair < int , int > > a, map < string, pair <int , int > > b)

{

   return a.second < b.second;

}

int main()

{

    map < string, pair <int , int > > mapi;

    mapi["peter"]=make_pair(2,4);

    mapi["ravsal"]=make_pair(4,23); 

    sort(mapi.begin(), mapi.end(), cmp);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You can't sort an `std::map` - it's always sorted by key. What's the ultimate goal of the exercise?

Comment: i was solving a problem i took the above structure to solve it.   you mean to say that there is no way to sort  map < string, pair < int , int > >  based on second or first value of pair? .

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean to say. `map<string, pait<int, int> >` is automatically sorted by its key - here, of type `string` - and cannot be sorted in any other way.